# Random linear arrangement of a tree with constrained edge lengths

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, sampling, random-graphs

Let $T$ be a tree with $V$ and edges $E$. Let a **linear arrangement** $\pi$ of $T$ be a bijective mapping from nodes to integers in the range $\{1, \dots, |V|\}$. You can think of $\pi$ as defining the position of each node in an arrangement on a line.

Now define the **length** of an edge $E = \{u,v\}$ in $T$ under $\pi$ to be the absolute value of the difference in positions for $u$ and $v$ according to the linear arrangement $\pi$:
\begin{equation}
 l_\pi(u,v) = |\pi(u) - \pi(v)|.
\end{equation}

Linear arrangements of this kind are studied in, for example, the Optimal Linear Arrangement problem (Chung, 1984), where the goal is to find a $\pi$ for a fixed $T$ which minimizes $\sum_{\{u,v\} \in E} l_\pi(u,v)$.

My problem is: given a tree $T$ and a linear arrangement $\pi$, generate new linear arrangement $\pi^\prime$ randomly at uniform from the set of possible linear arrangements of $T$ while preserving the same distribution over edge lengths as in the original $\pi$.

An example tree with linear arrangement $\pi$ is shown below. Each edge is marked with its length. The distribution of edge lengths in this tree under this particular linear arrangement is $(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)$ (3 of length 1 and 2 of length 2).

[image: Example tree]

Now here is the same tree under a different linear arrangement $\pi^\prime$, which has the same distribution of edge lengths $(1,1,1,2,2)$.

[image: Example tree 2]

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to generate random linear arrangements that preserve the distribution over edge lengths. Here is a baseline rejection-sampling algorithm:

1. Starting with tree $T$ with $n$ nodes and linear arrangement $\pi$, calculate the list of edge lengths for $T$ under $\pi$. Call this $L$.
2. Generate a random linear arrangement $\pi^\prime$ by drawing from the set of $n!$ linear arrangements of $T$.
3. Calculate the list of edge lengths for $T$ under $\pi^\prime$. Call this $L^\prime$. If $L^\prime = L$, accept the sample. If $L^\prime \neq L$, reject the sample and go to step 2.

I’m looking for an algorithm to draw a random sample from the linear arrangements that match $L$ which is faster than rejection sampling. No need to enumerate the whole set (although that would be nice too).

This question is related to, but distinct from, my earlier question: [Generate random labeled tree with constrained edge lengths](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116193/generate-random-labeled-tree-with-constrained-edge-lengths). In that question, I was looking for random trees. In this question, I am looking for random linear arrangements of a fixed tree, while preserving the topology of the tree.

Comment: What do you _actually_ want?  Since there may be n! many legal permutations, the algorithm cannot enumerate all in less time.  Is it faster "delay" that you are after?  Are you familiar with [bandwidth](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7810)?

Comment: I’m looking for a random sample, not an enumeration. Also, there are many fewer than n! linear arrangements that match the desired edge lengths.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bandwidth problem. In the language of my post, the bandwidth problem is asking if there exists a linear arrangement of a tree $T$ such that max(L) $\le b$. In my case, I already have a linear arrangement satisfying $L$ so I know at least one exists, and I’m looking for a uniform random sample of another one.

Comment: For many problems where finding one solution is hard, it's also hard to solve the variant where we are given one solution and asked whether a second solution exists.  I suggest seeing if you can adapt the proof techniques shown there to show that this applies to your situation as well.